# What could cause a token to remove faster than its expiry?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

So this is my first time adding cookies to my nodejs project, I have set my cookie and all which is working however i always seem to lose it faster than expected.

```
res.cookie('token', data.access_token, {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 600000),
    secure: false,
    httpOnly: true
})
```

So basically 600000 should be days worth of time right? However my token disappears within 30 minutes roughly.

So apart from reaching expiry and manually setting the expiry to current Date what else could kick a cookie off the board?

Comment: JavaScript uses milliseconds, in the code provided you're setting the expiry date 10 minutes from the set date.

Answer (score 1):

600000 means in milliseconds. So it is equal to just 10 minutes.